# What does " [this]" mean?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
ssc_event_cb_ts get_ssc_event_cb()
{
   return 
        [this](const uint8_t *data, size_t size, uint64_t ts)
        {
          UNUSED_VAR(ts);
          handle_ssc_event(data, size);
        };
}
```

I can guess that the function `get_ccs_event_cb` is to return an anonymous function. If I want to learn more about this kind of declaration, what topic should I learn?

Comment: I think you're talking about lambdas but your formatting is just painful to see. Please edit your post to make it readable.

Answer (score 4):

The `get_ssc_event_cb()` is returning a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), where `[this]` is the lambda's *captures* list.  The lambda is capturing the `this` pointer of the object that `get_ssc_event_cb()` is being called on, so the lambda can call `this->handle_ssc_event()` when the lambda itself is called, eg:

```cpp
someType obj;
auto cb = obj.get_ssc_event_cb();
cb(data, size, ts); // calls obj.handle_ssc_event(data, size);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a function returning a lambda. The expression inside `[]` in this context is known as `lambda capture`. It enables using specific variables from the surrounding scope inside the lambda.

Specifically, `[this]` means that `get_ssc_event_cb()` is a function member of a class, and the lambda can access members of the class. Apparently, `handle_ssc_event()` is such a member.

Answer (score 0):

I found a website: [Capture *this in lambda expression: Timeline of change](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1430524603/capture-this-in-lambda-expression-timeline-of-change). It's clear to learn.

Comment: Nice that you found that, but link-only answers are discouraged here, as they don't provide any useful info.  SO questions are intended to be self-contained, and links can break over time. You should copy the *relevant* info from that link into your answer so it actually answers the question asked.